# full working HelloWorld example for perl + SOAP + WSDL from a tarball

Tags: perl, soap

I wonder if anyone can provide a full working example of a `SOAP 1.2` server (no `CGI`) + `SOAP 1.2` client with a `WSDL` file.

Anything I try since 1 week fails.

My last try with `SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Daemon` module give me :

```
SOAP::Serializer::envelope: Client Denied access to method (AnalyzeDocument) in class (main) at /usr/share/perl5/site_perl/SOAP/Lite.pm line 2806
```

I have tons of Firefox tabs open about that, but none solution works in 2012.

`/usr/share/perl5/site_perl/SOAP/Lite.pm` relevant part is

```
# TODO - sort this mess out:
# The task is to test whether the class in question has already been loaded.
#
# SOAP::Lite 0.60:
#  unless (defined %{"${class}::"}) {
# Patch to SOAP::Lite 0.60:
# The following patch does not work for packages defined within a BEGIN block
#  unless (exists($INC{join '/', split /::/, $class.'.pm'})) {
# Combination of 0.60 and patch did not work reliably, either.
#
# Now we do the following: Check whether the class is main (always loaded)
# or the class implements the method in question
# or the package exists as file in %INC.
#
# This is still sort of a hack - but I don't know anything better
# If you have some idea, please help me out...
#
    unless (($class eq 'main') || $class->can($method_name)
        || exists($INC{join '/', split /::/, $class . '.pm'})) {

        # allow all for static and only specified path for dynamic bindings
        local @INC = (($static ? @INC : ()), grep {!ref && m![/\\.]!} $self->dispatch_to());
        eval 'local $^W; ' . "require $class";
        die "Failed to access class ($class): $@" if $@;
        $self->dispatched($class) unless $static;
    }

    die "Denied access to method ($method_name) in class ($class)"
        unless $static || grep {/^$class$/} $self->dispatched;

    return ($class, $method_uri, $method_name);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

This solution use `Apache` server + `mod_perl` on `Debian` (or derivate)

```
vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

add the block :

```
<Location /SOAP/>
    SetHandler perl-script
    PerlHandler Apache::SOAP
    PerlSetVar dispatch_to '/usr/share/perl5/'
</Location
```

`/usr/share/perl5/HelloWorld.pm` module file :

```
package HelloWorld;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub sayHello {
    return "Hello @_\n";
}

1;
```

SOAP client :

```
use SOAP::Lite +trace;

use strict; use warnings;

my $client = SOAP::Lite->new;
my $ua = $client->schema->useragent;
$ua->agent("Fubar! 0.1");

my $response = $client
    # WSDL url
    ->service("http://example.com/HelloWorld.xml") // the below exposed wsdl

    # method from SOAP server Module
    ->sayHello("foo", "bar");

print $response;
```

The `WSDL` file :

```
 <definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
   xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   xmlns:s0="urn:HelloWorld"
   targetNamespace="urn:HelloWorld"
   xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
   <types>
     <s:schema targetNamespace="urn:HelloWorld">
     </s:schema>
   </types>
   <message name="sayHello">
     <part name="name" type="s:string" />
     <part name="givenName" type="s:string" />
   </message>
   <message name="sayHelloResponse">
     <part name="sayHelloResult" type="s:string" />
   </message>

   <portType name="Service1Soap">
     <operation name="sayHello">
       <input message="s0:sayHello" />
       <output message="s0:sayHelloResponse" />
     </operation>
   </portType>

   <binding name="Service1Soap" type="s0:Service1Soap">
     <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"
         style="rpc" />
     <operation name="sayHello">
       <soap:operation soapAction="urn:HelloWorld#sayHello"/>
       <input>
         <soap:body use="encoded"
           encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
       </input>
       <output>
         <soap:body use="encoded"
           encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
       </output>
     </operation>
   </binding>
   <service name="HelloWorld">
     <port name="HelloWorldSoap" binding="s0:Service1Soap">
         <soap:address location="http://localhost:80/SOAP/" />
     </port>
   </service>
 </definitions>
```

Comment: Added original wsdl

Comment: It's not working. It's return error message of "SOAP::Transport::new: ()
SOAP::Serializer::new: ()
SOAP::Deserializer::new: ()
SOAP::Parser::new: ()
SOAP::Lite::new: ()
SOAP::Deserializer::new: ()
SOAP::Parser::new: ()
SOAP::Schema::new: ()
SOAP::Deserializer::deserialize: ()
SOAP::Parser::decode: ()
SOAP::Data::new: ()..........."

Answer (score 1):

Did you find this example?

http://jeredsutton.com/2010/05/28/perl-soaplite-example/

I corrected the typos in the original.

```
**use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Protocol::https;
use SOAP::Lite;

# Set SOAP username
my $USER = "user";

# Set SOAP password
my $PASSWORD = "password";

# Set SOAP API URL
my $SERVICE_LOC = 'https://localhost:2443';

# XML namespace
my $SERVICE_NS = 'http://name.space.domain/widget';
my $URI = $SERVICE_NS;

my $OUTPUT_XML = 'true';

# we use this lat
# The username and password are set by overriding the
# SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client::get_basic_credentials method
#### Authentication

sub SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client::get_basic_credentials {
   return $USER => $PASSWORD;
}


#### prototypes

sub method1;
sub method2;

#### CONNECT TO SERVICE

my $Service = SOAP::Lite-> proxy ($SERVICE_LOC);

$Service->outputxml($OUTPUT_XML);


#### Invoking Calls

print "\nHey does SOAP work?\n";

#### method1 Test

print "==> Invoking method1";
my $result1 = method1($Service);
if($OUTPUT_XML eq 'true'){
   print $result1;
} else {
   if($result1){
       for my $t ($result1->valueof('//tag/subtag')) {
         print $t->{value1} . " - " . $t->{value2} . "\n";
       }
   } else {
       print "no SOAP for you";
   }
}

#### method2 Test
my %DataStructure1 = (
   'data1'         => 'John Doe',
   'data2'         => '1234',
   );
my %DataStructure2 = (
   'data1'         => 'Jane Doe',
   'data2'         => '4321',
   );
my $result2 = method2($Service, \%DataStructure1, \%DataStructure2);
if($OUTPUT_XML eq 'true'){
   print $result2;
} else {
   if($result2){
       for my $t ($result2->valueof('//tag/subtag')) {
         print " " . $t->{value1} . " - " . $t->{value2} . " - " .
$t->{subsubtag}{value3} . "\n";
       }
   } else {
       print "no SOAP for you";
   }
}




#### Accessing Functions

sub method1{
   my $SOAP = shift;
   print "\n==> Invoking call method1\n";

   my $URIs;
   my $SOM = $SOAP->method1('');

   if($SOM){
       if($OUTPUT_XML eq 'true'){
           return $SOM;
       }elsif($SOM->fault) {
               die $SOM->faultstring;
       }else{
               return $SOM;
       }
   }

 return 0;
}

sub method2{
   my $Service            = $_[0];
   my $DataStructure1 = $_[1];
   my $DataStructure2 = $_[2];
   print "\n==> Invoking call method2\n";
   my  $Location = 'loc';

   my $Structure1 = SOAP::Data->name('structure1')->value([
                           SOAP::Data->name('data1')->value($DataStructure1->{'data1'}),
                           SOAP::Data->name('data2')->value($DataStructure1->{'data2'}),
                       ]);

   my $Structure2 = SOAP::Data->name('structure2')->value([
                           SOAP::Data->name('data1')->value($DataStructure2->{'data1'}),
                           SOAP::Data->name('data2')->value($DataStructure2->{'data2'}),
                       ]);

   my $Meth        = SOAP::Data->name('method2')->uri($SERVICE_NS);

   my $SOM         = $Service->call($Meth, $SERVICE_NS, $Location);

   if($SOM){
       if($OUTPUT_XML eq 'true'){
           return $SOM;
       }elsif($SOM->fault) {
               die $SOM->faultstring;
       }else{
               return $SOM;
       }
   }

   return 0;
}**
```

Comment: Thanks, but there's no wsdl in there.